# How to get an array of booleans as answer for a parameter "under 10"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to evaluate whether the number is under than 10, having as an answer an array of booleans.
I tried using forEach, map, but I didn't succeed in any attempt.

```
function underTen (arr){
  let underTenAnswer = arr.forEach(function(n){
    if (n < 10) {
      true;
    } else {
      false;
    }
  })
}
```

Input: underTen([1,9,12,19,4,16]
Expected outcome: Array [True, True, False, False, True, False]

I'm a beginner, sorry if something is notoriously incorrect.

Comment: [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It does not return anything

Comment: Do you need to track them individually or just know that all or some match your condition? `true;` and `false` on their own inside your `forEach()` function doesn't do anything.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ... the problem was I misunderstood the title thinking that all the elements had to match the condition.. instead later in the question was clear that he just wanted to check every single item and have a corresponding true/false. It was as easy as using a map. I'm afraid I misled the whole thread with my wrong comment that I deleted later.. considering the wrong answers arriving

Comment: The title of your question is very confusing; it does not really correspond to your description of what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really quick way to do this:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 8];

console.log(a.every((x) => x < 10)) // true
console.log(b.every((x) => x < 10)) // false
```

We use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here to check if each array element passes some condition.

If you need to return an array of booleans, then you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 8];
console.log(b.map((x) => x < 10)) // [true, true, true, true, false, true]
```

Comment: Perfect, an array of booleans, it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 2**: I thought I misunderstood the question but it seems this is what the OP wanted.

You can use the array helper `every` if you want to know if all array values match an expression:

```js
array.every(number => number < 10);
```

---

**Edit**: I misunderstood the question.

To get an array with boolean values according to an expression applied to each value:

```js
const newArray = array.map(number => number < 10);
```

Comment: Indeed. Changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The question suggests the output is to be an array with boolean values corresponding to each value in the test array.

`Array.map()` is ideally suited to this problem. Working snippet:

```js
const testArray = [1,9,12,19,4,16];

const resultsArray = testArray.map(element => (element < 10))

console.log(resultsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Use `Array#map` method; you have to return the result of `map` and the boolean values:

```js
function underTen (arr){
  return arr.map(function(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
}

console.log( underTen([1,9,12,19,4,16]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()`

```js
function underTen (arr){
  return arr.map(function(n){
    return (n < 10);
  })
}

console.log(underTen([1,9,12,19,4,16]));
```

```html
 Expected outcome: Array [True, True, False, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @evolutionxbox told you, forEach is returning nothing, so...

```js
function underTen (arr){
  let underTenAnswer = []
  
  arr.forEach(function(n){
    if (n < 10) {
      underTenAnswer.push(true);
    } else {
      underTenAnswer.push(false);
    }
  })
  return underTenAnswer
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the map function:

```
let result = [1,2,50,100,3].filter(x => x < 10);
```